# MongoDb SetUp in ubuntu16.0.4 ,shows Excess Arguements when systemd daemon-reload

Tags: mongodb

well I have followed the complete link 
https://www.howtoforge.com/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu-16.04/
and had been successfully created admin but as soon as I try the command

```
$ systemd daemon-reload
```

it shows in red coloured text
Excess arguements
and does nothing, well I am confused that whether this is an error or warning or not so essential.
Though i have not created the **mongod.service** file in **/etc/systemd/system** directory but still i have seen the same problem with those who have done it there too.
Please anyone make me understand this

Answer (score 0):

well I found out that, it  is showing the same problem when I do it with other systems which are running very finely over MongoDB, and even i have used it and it's running so it might be the problem with specification of the system or something related to extra parameters or dual files mongod.service in unix system